# Name for a particular type of set/set membership

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

This might be a philosophical rather than a mathematical distinction, but it there a name for a set whose members are selected on the basis of some property they hold, where the property is distinct from their identity? An example might be the set of all traffic lights which are currently showing red, where the fact that a particular light is on red is a transient property not to be considered as making up part of that object's identity.

Comment: What do you mean by "transient"? Can you give an example of where the number 3 would have a transient property?

Comment: An example for the number 3: is 3 in the set of numbers which are multiples of the number of letters in the name of the current month? So, a property which may change over time without affecting that number's essential "threeness"...